# Cambiar un item que contiene fecha a fecha en formato ISO 8601

Tags: php, composer

Hola(:tengo un path de un item que se llama $i_vis_dat que almacena las fechas de las visitas de los pacientes pero en formato mes, dia, año

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

qusiera cambiar esta para que me de la fecha en formato ISO8601

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado esto pero me sale ese error que no entiendo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también pensaba utilizar parse(toISODate pero no se de que forma poder indicar la division de MM-DD-YYYY que tiene el item para poder usarlo

Comment: Código como texto, por favor. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes pa transcribir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usa [DateTime::CreateFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Ver los [formatos disponibles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php#datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.parameters).

Ejemplos:

```php
<?php

$fecha1 = '05/20/2023';
$fecha2 = '06-02-2023 3:45:08 pm';

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $fecha1);
$dt2 = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s a', $fecha2);

echo $dt1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2023-05-20 20:15:28 (???)
echo $dt2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2023-02-06 15:45:08

// Si no se especifica la hora y quiere que permanezca en 00:00:00
$dt3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m/d/Y', $fecha1);
echo $dt3->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2023-05-20 00:00:00

// Formato ISO 8601
echo $dt2->format('c'); // 2023-02-06T15:45:08-05:00
```